# I am unable to mutate my store module from my component

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have a module called "moduleA" and its state contains "errorMessage" and a mutation called "storeErrorMessage". The error message renders in my component correctly but the problem is that I am unable to clear it before leaving the route. I have a mutation method in the moduleA called "clearErrorMessage" which is supposed to set the moduleA errorMessage state to null but it does not work that way.

See below some of my codes:

```
//In moduleA
const state = {
    errorMessage: "",
    okMessage: ""
}

const mutations = {
    storeErrorMessage(state, error) {
        state.errorMessage = error
    },
    storeOkMessage(state, okMessage) {
        state.okMessage = okMessage
    },
    clearOkMessage(state) {
        state.okMessage = null
    },
    clearErrorMessage(state) {
        state.errorMessage = null
    }
}

//In my component
methods: {
    ...mapMutations("moduleA", ["clearErrorMessage"]),
    ...mapMutations("moduleA", ["clearOkMessage"])
  },

beforeRouteLeave: (to, from, next) => {
    this.clearErrorMessage;
    this.clearOkMessage
    next();
  }
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong because the error and Ok messages are not being cleared. Please can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Right now you are not invoking/calling the mutations but simply returning their values, i.e. `this.clearErrorMessage;`. You should be invoking the functions using `()`, i.e. `this.clearErrorMessage();`.

In additional, you cannot use ES6 arrow function because that will bind lexcial this to your `beforeRouteLeave` method, which is *not* the component. [From the docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks):

> Don’t use arrow functions on an options property or callback, such as `created: () => console.log(this.a)` or `vm.$watch('a', newValue => this.myMethod())`. Since an arrow function doesn’t have a `this`, `this` will be treated as any other variable and lexically looked up through parent scopes until found

The following code should work:

```
beforeRouteLeave: function (to, from, next) => {
    this.clearErrorMessage();
    this.clearOkMessage();
    next();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Terry for your response. I did not add those brackets because the only argument they take is the state. However, after adding them, I got this error "TypeError: _this2.clearErrorMessage is not a function
    at VueComponent.beforeRouteLeave". Please do you have any idea what causes that?

Comment: @Efosa Are the methods and beforeRouteLeave in the same component? What happens when you try to log `this` to console?

Comment: Yes the map mutations methods and the beforeRouteLeave are in the same component. Console.log(this) in the methods and in the beforeRouteLeave look very different. The one in the beforeRouteLeave is mucher fewer and contains beforeCreate: (2) [ƒ, ƒ]
beforeDestroy: [ƒ]
beforeRouteLeave: ƒ beforeRouteLeave(to, from, next)
computed: {error: ƒ}
created: ƒ created()
data: ƒ data()
methods: {onSubmit: ƒ, clearErrorMessage: ƒ, clearOkMessage: ƒ}
render: ƒ ()
staticRenderFns: (2) [ƒ, ƒ]
_Ctor: {0: ƒ}

Comment: Thanks Terry. Now I have solved it after using ES5 function instead of ES6 arrow function.

Comment: Oh yes, that's something I've missed. If you use arrow function, the `this` does not actually refer to your VueJS app/component.

Answer (score 0):

Now I have solved it using the ES5 standard function, instead of the ES6 arrow function, as shown below:

```
beforeRouteLeave: function (to, from, next){
    console.log(this)
    this.clearErrorMessage();
    this.clearOkMessage();
    next();
  }
```